# Evaluate $\int_0^2 \int_{-\sqrt{2-x^2}}^\sqrt{2-x^2}x^3+xy^2 dydx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to evaluate the following integral

> $$I=\int_0^2 \int_{-\sqrt{2-x^2}}^\sqrt{2-x^2}x^3+xy^2 dydx$$

What would be the best way to approach this integral? Suppose we have $0\le x \le\sqrt{2}$, then this integral can be evaluated by

$$\tilde{I} = \int_0^\sqrt{2}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2}\left(r^3\cos^3(\theta)+r^3\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)\right)rd\theta dr$$

After using some algebra and trigonometry, we have

$$\tilde{I}=\frac{8}{5}\sqrt{2}$$

However, I do not know what I should do when $\sqrt{2}\le x \le 2$ and I have never seen this kind of integral before. WolframAlpha suggests that

$$I = \frac{8}{5}\sqrt{2}+\frac{56}{15}\sqrt{2}i$$

So apparently I am missing the "imaginary part". How do we get that answer? Is there any complex analysis technique that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is perfectly correct.

What you ended with is basically $$I=\int_0^t \int_{-\sqrt{2-x^2}}^\sqrt{2-x^2}(x^3+xy^2)\, dy\,dx=\frac{4}{15} \left(\sqrt{2-t^2} \left(t^2+1\right) t^2+6
   \left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2-t^2}\right)\right)$$ and you noticed the problem for $t>\sqrt 2$. Replacing $t=2$ leads to the result. $$I=\frac{4}{15} \left(\sqrt{2-4} \left(4+1\right) 4+6
   \left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2-4}\right)\right)=\frac{4}{15} \left(20\sqrt{-2}+6\sqrt 2-6\sqrt{-2}\right)$$ $$I=\frac{4}{15} \left(14\sqrt{-2}+6\sqrt 2\right)=\frac{4}{15} \left(14\sqrt{2i^2}+6\sqrt 2\right)=\frac{4}{15} \left(14\sqrt{2}i+6\sqrt 2\right)$$ $$I=\frac{4}{15} \times 14\sqrt{2}i+\frac{4}{15} \times6\sqrt 2=\frac{8}{5}\sqrt{2}+\frac{56}{15}\sqrt{2}i$$

Comment: This makes sense. What confused me is this. Suppose we have an integral $\int_{-\sqrt{2}i}^{\sqrt{2}i} x dx$, What does this integral mean? I am asking this because, it seems like this is "essentially" what we get when $t > \sqrt{2}$.